# Subdomain redirect to file

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}                                 ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.imvu-e\.com$
RewriteCond     /var/imvu/products/ht/clients/%1/            -d
RewriteRule     ^(.+)                                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1
RewriteRule     ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+?)\.imvu-e\.com/(.*)        /var/www/imvu/products/ht/clients/$1/$2 [L]
```

I would like

`anything.imvu-e.com` to redirect to the files at `/var/imvu/products/ht/clients/anything/`

Thus `http://anything.imvu-e.com/woot.php?var=4` goes to `/var/imvu/products/ht/clients/anything/woot.php` sending it `var=4`

The way it is now to access it would be `http://www.imvu-e.com/products/ht/clients/anything/woot.php?var=4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a nice `VirtualDocumentRoot` instead?

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/imvu/products/ht/clients/%-3
```

Comment: This seems to mess up my relative links where I use `../` in the URL or for images. Id rather them type in anything.imvu-e.com and be redirected to the long URL